# Issue with infinite loops in a graph

Tags: recursion, graph, infinite-loop

I have idea for an app in which I want to calculate the rank of the users based on other people ranks that vote up/appreciate the user, but now I have a problem when one user vote up and that other user vote up in return. I will have a graph of users with loops that will be infinite. Is it possible to create such ranking+voting system without loops in a graph.

Anybody have an idea how to solve this? I know it's not code related but concept that can be implemented.

Comment: I don't understand your question, basically the way you usually do it is by adding the seen boolean variable during the actual rank calculation so you don't visit the same graph node twice.

Comment: @cerkiewny But how to calculate rank of user A if it's based on B, B need to be calculated before A, but it can't because A is not calulated before B, so they need to wait for each other.

Comment: the same way you do calculate all borders of the decreasing series... you need to take a look at some multidimensional calculations, there are several ways to calculate such problems but I am not an expert, I will try to find some resources for you. For sure you can calculate first ranks with the "seen" flag, than you can recalculate them based on differences from first approximation... The more times you do such thing the more accurate actual rank will be.